# call c# from c++, return value

Tags: c#, c++, com, unmanaged, managed

I am trying to call C# code from C++. So I chose the COM Interop way. Now I have C# code:

```
namespace ToBeCalled
{
    [Guid("9329feaf-b293-4093-a7d8-6128f52b30a6")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IInterface
    {
        int Write(string toWrite);
    }
}

namespace ToBeCalled
{
    [Guid("e4105e40-2d6b-4b7c-ae42-d2f9c405a2a0")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class ClassYouWantToUse : IInterface
    {
        public int Write(string toWrite)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(toWrite);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And c++ code

```
#import "...\\ToBeCalled.tlb"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Create the interface pointer.
    ToBeCalled::IInterfacePtr piTest(__uuidof(ToBeCalled::ClassYouWantToUse));

    long lResult = 0;

    // Call the Add method.
    piTest->Write("hi", &lResult);

    wprintf(L"The result is %d\n", lResult);

    // Uninitialize COM.
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

When I try this compile, of course it says that Write doesn't take 2 arguments. I saw the MSDN, where they have example like this and they take the return value this way. So my question is, how can I obtain the return value of the function? When I update the call to

```
piTest->Write("hi");
```

than execution fails on Unhandled Exception. When I tried this example without returning value, so declaration of the return value for method is void, than everything works ok.

Comment: I found that is need to add out parameter to c# and then I can use the second argument to function which will have the result value. Ok, so for Int the problem is solved, but how can I send the string like this?

Comment: You should be able to normally return a value, and not via `[out]` parameter. What is exactly the exception? Have you debugged the managed call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server code is OK and you don't need to use an `out` parameter.

The client code should look simply like this:

```
long result = piTest->Write("hi");
```

If you look inside generated `.tlh` file, you will see that signature is something like:

```
long Write(_bstr_t toWrite);
```

This is a generated wrapper code, and you are probably confusing it with raw COM call which is also a part of the `tlh` file and looks like this:

```
virtual HRESULT __stdcall raw_Write(BSTR toWrite, long* pRetVal) = 0;
```

The wrapper is more convenient: it calls the raw COM call internally and handles the return value - thus, the return value is normally returned from the function (instead of as an `[out, retval]` argument), and if the result of raw call denotes an error (a failed `HRESULT`) a `_com_error` exception is thrown.

For details, you can take a look at another generated file, with `tli` extension, which contains the implementation of wrapper method.

Comment: thanks, I try it. Yes, I was confused with HRESULT. Is need here to make some deallocation, when I am returning string from c#? If yes, how?

Comment: You are not returning a string so nothing to deallocate. If you create a new method which returns a string (defined as an `[out, retval]` argument in `idl` definition), it conforms to standard COM rules and in general you would have to deallocate it via `SysFreeString` API (e.g. if you use raw call). However, `#import` will also generate a 'smart' wrapper which will return an `bstr_t`, which takes care of deallocating it for you, so if you use that method, there is nothing to deallocate.